# What is the relationship between `v8::Isolate` class and `v8::internal::Isolate` in V8

Tags: v8

I am studying the source code of V8 recently. There are 2 definitions of  `Isolate` class, one in `v8::Isolate` and the other in `v8::internal::Isolate`. It seems that `v8::Isolate` uses `v8::internal::Isolate`, but I could not understand the relationship between these 2 definitions/

I have tried to look into the class defitions of both, `v8::Isolate` in https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h#L7391 and `v8::internal::Isolate` in https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/execution/isolate.h#L452

but could not figure it out.

To be more specific, in  `v8::Isolate::New`(https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/api/api.cc#L7903), it returns a C++ object of type `v8::Isolate`.

```
Isolate* Isolate::New(const Isolate::CreateParams& params) {
  Isolate* isolate = Allocate();
  Initialize(isolate, params);
  return isolate;
}
```

But internally in `Allocate` function, it returns an object of type `v8::internal::Isolate`, and reinterpret_casted to `v8::Isolate`

```
Isolate* Isolate::Allocate() {
    return reinterpret_cast<Isolate*>(i::Isolate::New());
}
```

How can object of class `v8::Isolate` be casted from `v8::internal::Isolate`?

Can anyone familiar with V8 give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a technique not unusual for libraries: `v8::internal::Isolate` is the implementation, but its details are entirely encapsulated within the library, and hidden from the public API. `v8::Isolate` is just an opaque reference. Observe how it has no fields; embedders know nothing about what it looks like in memory (or whether it has a memory representation at all -- as far as they are concerned, it could be something like a kernel's file descriptor). The reason for this encapsulation, of course, is to separate concerns, and to make components independent from each other: the library can change the internal definition of the class without embedders having to care (i.e. they can't possibly depend on the internal state, so it's guaranteed they won't be broken by changes; they don't even have to get recompiled because the public API [and ABI] doesn't change when the internal class layout changes).

Consider this reduced example demonstrating the principle:

```
/* public API */

class BlackBox {
public:
  static BlackBox* Create();
  void DoSomething();
}

void StandaloneFunction(BlackBox* box);


/* internal implementation */

class TheRealThing {
 public:
  TheRealThing(int value) : value_(value) {}

 private:
  int value_;
}

BlackBox* BlackBox::Create() {
  TheRealThing* real = new TheRealThing(42);
  return reinterpret_cast<BlackBox*>(real);
}

void BlackBox::DoSomething() {
  TheRealThing* real = reinterpret_cast<TheRealThing*>(this);
  printf("Hello %d\n", real->value_);
}

void StandaloneFunction(BlackBox* box) {
  TheRealThing* real = reinterpret_cast<TheRealThing*>(box);
  printf("Good bye %d\n", real->value_);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am still confused.

Take your code example above as example, `Create` returns an object of class `TheRealThing`, though reinterpreted as `BlackBox`, the underlying memory layout is still the same as `TheRealThing`, so when we call methods in `BlackBox`, wouldn't the methods defined in `TheRealThing` be called instead?

Comment: No, that's not how method calling works. Maybe it helps to assume that `this` in C++ is implicitly passed like the explicit `self` in Python. The non-static `void BlackBox::DoSomething()` can be seen as syntactic sugar for a hypothetical `static void BlackBox::DoSomething(BlackBox* this)`.

Comment: @benquike There's no dynamic dispatch here. The client only knows about, and directly calls, the `BlackBox` methods.

Comment: FWIW, you can avoid the reinterpret casts and replace them with safer static casts by defining TheRealThing as a subclass of BlackBox.